# MySQL error "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, constraint

Estou iniciando na linguagem SQL. Estou com o seguinte erro:

```
Table 'linces.controlos' doesn't exist
```

Ainda não encontrei a solução, alguém pode ajudar?

```
Drop Database if Exists Linces;
Create Database Linces;
Use Linces;

Create Table Linces(
Id_lince int NOT NULL,
Nome_lince char(50),
Genero char(50),
Data_obito datetime,
Id_pai int NOT NULL, 
Id_mae int NOT NULL,
Primary Key (Id_lince) 
);

Create Table Localizacoes(
Id_lince int NOT NULL,
Datahora datetime NOT NULL,
latitude double,
longitude double,
Constraint pk_Localizacoes Primary Key (Id_lince, Datahora),
Constraint ch_estr_Id_lince
Foreign Key (Id_lince)
References Linces (Id_lince) 
On Update Cascade
On Delete Cascade
);

Create Table Tecnicos(
Id_func int NOT NULL,
Nome_func char(50) Not Null,
Primary Key (Id_func)
);

Create Table Controlos(
Id_lince int NOT NULL,
Dat datetime NOT NULL,
Id_func int Not Null,
Peso double,
Estado_saude char(50) Not Null,
Constraint pk_Controlos Primary Key (Id_lince, dat, Id_func),
Constraint ch_estr_Id_lince
Foreign Key (Id_lince)
References Linces (Id_lince)
On Update Cascade
On Delete Set Null,
Constraint ch_estr_Id_func
Foreign Key (Id_func)
References Tecnicos (Id_func)
On Update Cascade
On Delete Cascade
);
```

Comment: Em qual momento deu o erro?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em:

```
Constraint ch_estr_Id_lince Foreign Key (Id_lince) References Linces (Id_lince) On Update Cascade On Delete Set Null
```

Nessa linha você quer setar uma coluna NULL quando ela está com a propriedade `NOT NULL`

```
Id_lince int NOT NULL,
```

A solução é mudar o `On Delete`, mesmo depois de mudar ele, você está criando duas chaves estrangeiras com o mesmo nome:

```
Create Table Localizacoes(
Constraint ch_estr_Id_lince Foreign Key (Id_lince) References Linces (Id_lince) On Update Cascade On Delete Cascade
...
Create Table Controlos(
Constraint ch_estr_Id_lince Foreign Key (Id_lince) References Linces (Id_lince) On Update Cascade On Delete Set Null
```

A solução é mudar o nome de uma key.

Para checar os erros específicos, você pode rodar a query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` e procurar por `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`.